# java warnings on linux

Tags: java, linux

Hello i am getting warnings after i have installed java on kubuntu 11.10. The java programs run but i always get 4 warnings:

```
$ java
Warning: no leading - on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: missing VM type on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: no leading - on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: missing VM type on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
```

What am i missing? Thanks in advance!

Here is the file content /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
#
# %W% %E%
#
# Copyright (c) 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
#
# List of JVMs that can be used as an option to java, javac, etc.
# Order is important -- first in this list is the default JVM.
# NOTE that this both this file and its format are UNSUPPORTED and
# WILL GO AWAY in a future release.
#
# You may also select a JVM in an arbitrary location with the
# "-XXaltjvm=<jvm_dir>" option, but that too is unsupported
# and may not be available in a future release.
#
-server KNOWN
-client IGNORE
-hotspot ERROR
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: The folks over at ubuntu.stackexchange.com might be able to help you.

Comment: well i installed repository and then through install manager muon (for the on for kubuntu version). It installed many dependencies and it works even with eclipse but i get those warnings. I also see those warnings in the eclipse console but the programs run...

Comment: Please attach the contents of the /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg file to your question.

Comment: @Dave I just uploade the file content :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing `#` in the first line before the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun` in `jvm.cfg` file. I have not figured out why it was missing. Now its working fine without any warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through the following procedures?

Open terminal and run the following commands

Add partner repository using the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner”
```

Update the source list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install sun java packages using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

The above command will download all the required packages and begins the installation, you’ll get a screen that contains the Sun Operating System Distributor License for Java and hit Enter to continue.

You’ll see a dialog that asks you if you agree with the DLJ license terms. Select Yes, and hit Enter; the JRE will finish installing.

Testing Java Runtime Environment

You’ll want to confirm that your system is configured properly for Sun’s JRE. This is a two-step process.

First, check that the JRE is properly installed by running the following command from a terminal.

Comment: Yes i have installed it correctly. As i said programs can run but i always get those errors...

Comment: Well your answer didnt solve anything. Btw check again your answer... Did you want to add something in the end and you forget it? "running the following command from a terminal." ??